# Is it possible to use GTKmm 3 without rtti?

Tags: c++, rtti, gtkmm

I am currently wondering if there is a way to use GTKmm 3 without the rtti data. For some reason everytime I try to compile it with `-fno-rtti` I get errors in the header files.

So is there a way to use GTKmm 3 without rtti data or can I stop looking for any possibility?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Because our tool is compiled without rtti data for several reasons and gtkmm uses typeid in the header files. so you cannot use gtkmm without rtti

Comment: what's your tool name?

Comment: why is that relevant?

Comment: Because I'd like to help

Comment: The Name of our tool wont help you as you wont have access to the src...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115208/discussion-between-fnc12-and-nidhoegger).